# Laravel Eloquent - Eager loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have three tables: `Client`, `User`, `Position`. Client to User is many-to-many, Client to Position is one-to-many and User to Position is many-to-many.

Now, a `User` can be part of two different `Clients`, and so for each, this user is assigned to some positions. I want to get the client, and all of its users, and their position.

When I use:

```
Client::whereId($id)
       ->with(array(
         'users',
         'users.positions'
       ))
       ->firstOrFail()
```

Then, I do get all the users for the client, but I get all the positions the user has, from all of the clients they are part of.

What can I do?

**Example**

->Say I have two clients: Sony and Microsoft, and two users John and Mike.

->Say that Microsoft has positions: Developer and Engineer.

->Say that Sony has positions: Marketing and Finance.

John works at Microsoft as Developer, while Mike works at Microsoft as an Engineer and at Sony as a Finance guy.

If I want to get all Microsoft's employees and their positions, I expect to get John (and his position being Developer) and Mike (and his position being Finance).

However, the code above that I run gives me John (with Developer), and Mike (with Engineer and Finance. The pivot table for Finance clearly says it is for Sony).

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, it's not clear?

Comment: Sorry! I gave an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. I had to apply constraints to my eager loading:

```
<?php
Client::with(array(
          'users',
          'users.positions' => function($query) {
              $query->whereClientId($id);
          }
        ))
        ->find($id);
```

This worked perfectly!